# Get child value on the parent without triggering eventemiiter in angular v6

Tags: angular

Angular v6.

Have a Parent component which has a send button.

A Card Component in which multiple inputs are present list/ comments/checkbox etc.

Parent component loops and calls the card component.

Example:

```
<div>
   <div *ngFor="3 times">
      <card-component></card-component>
   </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way without clicking any thing to get the values of the child component while pressing the send button on the parent.

Eventemitter requires an action like a click on the child, but is there any way to get the child component details when clicking the send button on the parent.

[Rough image of the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I01Gn.png)

Comment: Just use an `@Output()` property, you don't necessarily have to click on anything to send the event, you could make the child fire when it is initialized.

Comment: hmm.. Want the reverse. When the parent presses send, the child details need to be fetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In parent component ts, use:

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;
```

And use it to access its properties and methods, after the child component gets properly rendered:

```
console.log(this.child.your_child_variable);
```

Comment: Hmm.. But my children are in a loop.

Comment: You can use @ViewChildren(ChildComponent) children: QueryList<ChildComponent>;

Comment: Works. Thanks Prachi.